# Nvcc has different version than CUDA

Tags: linux, cuda, nvcc

I got installed cuda 7, but when I hit nvcc --version, it prints out 6.5. I would like to install Theano library on GTX 960 card, but it needs nvcc 7.0.
Ive tried reinstall cuda, but it didn't update nvcc. When I run apt-get install nvidida-cuda-toolkit, it instals only 6.5.

How can I update nvcc to version 7.0 ?

Comment: After installing CUDA 7, you will need to update your environment variables, like your `PATH` variable.  Have you done that?  You might wish to follow the instructions in the [installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#abstract) carefully.

Comment: please, see my comment under first answer. I don't see any uninstall cuda files.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall old CUDA versions.  Did you [update your environment variables](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#mandatory-post) as I already asked?

Comment: maybe not, how do I do that with new cuda version?

Comment: See the text in my comment that is in blue?  Click on it.

Comment: well, now I'm getting 
The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to start over and follow the installation guide carefully.  Note that the installation guide is linked in blue above in my original comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the official installation guide to uninstall your current cuda environment and then install the lateest CUDA developing environment, it includes cudaSDK, cudatoolkit and driver.

Comment: If you mean "2.7. Handle Conflicting Installation Methods" in instalation guide, I don't see any 
/usr/local/cuda-X.Y/bin/uninstall_cuda_X.Y.pl
or 
/usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall :(

Comment: I know that this might not be relevant or helpful to the originator of this question, but for others who might be looking for answers to this question, I would highly recommend the answer under [Different CUDA versions shown by nvcc and NVIDIA-smi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi). The answer there clears up a lot of the confusion.