# Different CUDA versions shown by nvcc and NVIDIA-smi

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am very confused by the different CUDA versions shown by running `which nvcc` and `nvidia-smi`. I have both cuda9.2 and cuda10 installed on my ubuntu 16.04. Now I set the PATH to point to cuda9.2. So when I run

```sh
$ which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin/nvcc
```

However, when I run

```
$ nvidia-smi
Wed Nov 21 19:41:32 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.72       Driver Version: 410.72       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   53C    P0    26W /  N/A |    379MiB /  6078MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1324      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           225MiB |
|    0      2844      G   compiz                                       146MiB |
|    0     15550      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
|    0     19992      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
|    0     23605      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
```

So am I using cuda9.2 as `which nvcc` suggests, or am I using cuda10 as `nvidia-smi` suggests? I [saw this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319877/nvcc-has-different-version-than-cuda) but it does not provide direct answer to the confusion, it just asks us to reinstall the CUDA Toolkit, which I already did.

Comment: I think I've seen this exact question come up multiple times over the last couple days. But I can't seem to find a duplicate now. The answer is: nvidia-smi shows you the CUDA version that your driver supports. You have one of the recent 410.x drivers installed which support CUDA 10. The version the driver supports has nothing to do with the version you compile and link your program against. A driver that supports CUDA 10.0 will also be able to run an application that was built for CUDA 9.2…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I see. Thanks for the clarification! Guess I'm using CUDA9.2 then..

Comment: A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288157/cuda-version-mismatch).  @MichaelKenzel if you want to add an answer I would upvote.

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes, that was the one I was looking for. I only learned the answer from your comment there, so if anyone deserves an upvote then it is you yourself ;)

Answer (score 394, accepted):

CUDA has 2 primary APIs, the runtime and the driver API. Both have a corresponding version (e.g. 8.0, 9.0, etc.)

The necessary support for the driver API (e.g. `libcuda.so` on linux) is installed by the GPU driver installer.

The necessary support for the runtime API (e.g. `libcudart.so` on linux, and also `nvcc`) is installed by the CUDA toolkit installer (which may also have a GPU driver installer bundled in it).

In any event, the (installed) driver API version may not always match the (installed) runtime API version, especially if you install a GPU driver independently from installing CUDA (i.e. the CUDA toolkit).

The `nvidia-smi` tool gets installed by the GPU driver installer, and generally has the GPU driver in view, not anything installed by the CUDA toolkit installer.

Recently (somewhere between 410.48 and 410.73 driver version on linux) the powers-that-be at NVIDIA decided to add reporting of the CUDA Driver API version installed by the driver, in the output from `nvidia-smi`.

This has no connection to the installed CUDA runtime version.

`nvcc`, the CUDA compiler-driver tool that is installed with the CUDA toolkit, will always report the CUDA runtime version that it was built to recognize.  It doesn't know anything about what driver version is installed, or even if a GPU driver is installed.

Therefore, by design, these two numbers don't necessarily match, as they are reflective of two different things.

If you are wondering why `nvcc -V` displays a version of CUDA you weren't expecting (e.g. it displays a version other than the one you think you installed) or doesn't display anything at all, version wise, it may be because you haven't followed the mandatory instructions in step 7 (prior to CUDA 11) (or step  6 in the CUDA 11 linux install guide) of the [cuda linux install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)

Note that although this question mostly has linux in view, the same concepts apply to **windows** CUDA installs.  The driver has a CUDA driver version associated with it (which can be queried with `nvidia-smi`, for example).  The CUDA runtime also has a CUDA runtime version associated with it.  The two will not necessarily match in all cases.

In most cases, if `nvidia-smi` reports a CUDA version that is numerically equal to or higher than the one reported by `nvcc -V`, this is not a cause for concern.  That is a defined compatibility path in CUDA (newer drivers/driver API support "older" CUDA toolkits/runtime API).  For example if `nvidia-smi` reports CUDA 10.2, and `nvcc -V` reports CUDA 10.1, that is generally not cause for concern.  It should just work, and it does not necessarily mean that you "actually installed CUDA 10.2 when you meant to install CUDA 10.1"

If `nvcc` command doesn't report anything at all (e.g. `Command 'nvcc' not found...`) or if it reports an unexpected CUDA version, this may also be due to an incorrect CUDA install, i.e the mandatory steps mentioned above were not performed correctly. You can start to figure this out by using a linux utility like `find` or `locate` (use man pages to learn how, please) to find your `nvcc` executable. Assuming there is only one, the path to it can then be used to fix your PATH environment variable.  The [CUDA linux install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#mandatory-post) also explains how to set this.  You may need to adjust the CUDA version in the PATH variable to match your actual CUDA version desired/installed.  It's also possible that you have not installed the CUDA toolkit at all (`nvcc` is provided via a CUDA toolkit install, not by a GPU driver install alone.)

Similarly, when using docker, the `nvidia-smi` command will generally report the driver version installed on the base machine, whereas other version methods like `nvcc --version` will report the CUDA version installed inside the docker container.

Similarly, if you have used another installation method for the CUDA "toolkit" such as Anaconda, you may discover that the version indicated by Anaconda does not "match" the version indicated by `nvidia-smi`.  However, the above comments still apply.  Older CUDA toolkits installed by Anaconda can be used with newer versions reported by `nvidia-smi`, and the fact that `nvidia-smi` reports a newer/higher CUDA version than the one installed by Anaconda does not mean you have an installation problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70048525/why-does-python-show-a-wrong-cuda-version) is another question that covers similar ground.  The above treatment does not in any way indicate that this answer is only applicable if you have installed multiple CUDA versions intentionally or unintentionally.  The situation presents itself *any time you install CUDA*.  The version reported by `nvcc` and `nvidia-smi` may not match, and that is **expected** behavior and in most cases quite normal.

If the version reported by `nvidia-smi` is a numerically lower value than the version reported by `nvcc`, I would consider that to be probably a broken config.  If you compile code with that `nvcc` and then try to run it on that machine, it is not likely to work.   There are [compatibility exceptions](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/) to this principle (enabled via installation of the "forward-compatibility package").  In this situation my general advice (which is true for a great many issues) is to update the GPU driver version to the latest available for your GPU.

Comment: [Difference between the driver and runtime APIs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/driver-vs-runtime-api.html) according to Nvidia.

Comment: @Rober Crovella Thanks for the clearity. I have the same situation nvidia-smi shows CUDA version 10.1 and nvcc shows 9.1. Now is it okay to train the network or does the installation is okay still works?

Comment: I followed the post-installation steps, but still, nvcc and nvidia-smi are showing different cuda version

Comment: That's entirely possible.  If you installed the latest driver (causing `nvidia-smi` to display CUDA 10.2, currently) but an earlier version of CUDA (say, 10.1) then there will be a difference reported by `nvidia-smi` as compared to `nvcc`.  It's not a problem in that case.

Comment: The comment is helpful, but doesn't explain what happens if `nvcc` reports a higher version (say 10.2) than `nvidia-smi` (say 10.1). In that case, the Cuda tries to compile it as 10.2 and tries to run it on 10.1. This usually results in runtime error, `"RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device"` as an example.

Comment: Mind-blowing explanation, I've been struggling why conda is showing different version than nvidia-smi, your post explained it all.

Comment: @TheSaurus IMHO it won't work.  Have a look at the issue that I faced and how I solved it by upgrading CUDA driver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139806/pytorch-with-cuda-local-installation-fails

Comment: @RobertCrovella, would you please spare a few moments to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318677/libtorch-and-cuda-stub-library-loaded-at-runtime-problem ? Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Made this figure for people, hope that makes it more clear. I now finally understand why the version of nvidia-smi can be higher than the one of nvcc, it's because nvidia-smi shows the version of the Driver (which is the lowest-level). nvcc is higher-level, so a lower version for that one is not a problem.

Based on the top-voted answer by @Robert Crovella.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`nvcc` is in the CUDA bin folder - as such check if the CUDA bin folder has been added to your `$PATH`.

Specifically, ensure that you have carried out the CUDA Post-Installation actions (e.g. from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)):

1. Add the CUDA Bin to `$PATH` (i.e. add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`)

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/NsightCompute-2019.1${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

> PS. Ensure the following two paths above, exist first: `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin` and `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/NsightCompute-2019.1` (the NsightCompute path could have a slightly different ending depending on the version of Nsight compute installed...

2. Update `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (i.e. add the following line to your `~/bashrc`).

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

After this, both `nvcc` and `nvidia-smi` (or `nvtop`) report the same version of CUDA...

Comment: That's because the $PATH$ specifies using CUDA 10. But some software require different versions of CUDA.

Comment: `NsightCompute-2019.1` is called `NsightCompute-1.0` in CUDA 10.0.

Comment: I followed the post-installation steps, but still, nvcc and nvidia-smi are showing different cuda version

Comment: everytime i open the terminal i have to run the two paths command (from cuda post installation in step7). is there a way I can persist the state and not having to to run the path commands repeatedly?

Comment: @monti Yes you can write the command to `.bashrc` or `bash_profile` so it automatically loads for each bash session. See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix

Answer (score 6):

`nvidia-smi` can show a “different CUDA version” from the one that is reported by `nvcc`. Because they are reporting two different things:

`nvidia-smi` shows that maximum available CUDA version support for a given GPU driver.
And the 2nd thing which `nvcc -V` reports is the CUDA version that is currently being used by the system.

In short

`nvidia-smi` shows the highest version of CUDA supported by your driver. `nvcc -V` shows the version of the current CUDA installation. As long as your driver-supported version is higher than your installed version, it's fine. You can even have several versions of CUDA installed at the same time.

Comment: this answer is also correct, why is it getting downvoted; nvidia-smi jsut shows max supported cuda version by driver and does not really even imply if Cuda is installed.

Answer (score 2):

The discrepancy between the CUDA versions reported by `nvcc --version` and `nvidia-smi` is due to the fact that they report different aspects of your system's CUDA setup.

- `nvcc --version` reports the version of the CUDA toolkit you have installed. This is the version that is used to compile CUDA code.
- `nvidia-smi`, on the other hand, reports the maximum CUDA version that your GPU driver supports.

In your case, `nvcc --version` is reporting CUDA 10.1 because that's the version of the CUDA toolkit you have installed. `nvidia-smi` is reporting a different version because your GPU driver can support up to that CUDA version.

When you run a CUDA program, the CUDA version that gets used is determined by the version of the CUDA toolkit that was used to compile the program. However, the CUDA version used by the program must also be supported by your GPU driver. If your GPU driver does not support the CUDA version used by the program, you will encounter errors.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, this is because there are two different versions of CUDA toolkits installed, one of which is old and still on path. For example, my distro had pre-installed version at `/usr/bin/nvcc`. After I installed new version, it was at default path `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc`. Use `which nvcc` to find paths on your system.

There is no need to worry about this. You can fix it simply by adding following in .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using cuda 10.2 :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:/opt/nvidia/nsight-compute/2019.5.0${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

might help because when I checked, there was no directory for nsight-compute in cuda-10.2.
I am not sure if this was just the problem with me or else why wouldn't they mention it in the official documentation.