# TensorFlow Not Detecting NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 6GB GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having trouble getting TensorFlow to detect my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 6GB GPU. I have installed TensorFlow, CUDA, and cuDNN, and my computer recognizes the GPU, but when I try to use TensorFlow, it says that no GPU is available. Here is the error message I get:

```
import tensorflow as tf


print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Num GPUs Available: 0
```

I have already tried installing TensorFlow 2.15, but the problem persists. I'm running Python 3.9.1, CUDA 12.3.2, and cuDNN 8.9.7.29. I have checked the NVIDIA Control Panel and my GPU is enabled.And I have also added cuda and cudnn to the path.

I'm not sure what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Details:

```
OS: Windows 11
CPU: Intel Core i5-13420h
RAM: 16 GB
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 6GB
Python: 3.9.1
TensorFlow: 2.10.1
CUDA: 12.3.2
cuDNN: 8.9.7.29
```

I hope this is enough information to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: CUDA 12 appears not to be compatible with TF2.10. You may need to downgrade to CUDA 11.2? Source: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/does-tensorflow-2-10-or-2-11-support-support-cuda-11-6/14561/9

Comment: @slothrop I thought that this number is the minimum possible version and there is no problem if it is higher. isn't it?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. CUDA is generally backward-compatible, but using a later version than intended may require rebuilding from source. For example: look at this thread: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-2-14-and-cuda-12-status/19725. The OP couldn't use TF 2.13 with CUDA 12. One of the other people on the thread could, but only after building from source. This isn't directly related to TF 2.10, but it shows the kind of problems that can arise.

Comment: From the error messages, that version of TensorFlow expects CUDA 11.0, no other version will work.

Comment: Here's another example of someone who had to downgrade CUDA in order to make TF work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227372/pytorch-vs-tensorflow-cuda-versions

Comment: @slothrop According to this address: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.2.0-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exelocal I can't run cuda 11.2 on Windows 11 right? But I have Windows 11

Comment: Hmm, that might be a problem, not sure the Windows 10 version will work. To be honest, using WSL might be less hassle here - that way you can use the latest Tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the problem was due to the lack of compatibility with the cuda version and it should be downgraded, the 11.2 version which is compatible with tensorflow 2.10.1 was not compatible with Windows 11, so the first version after that which supports Windows 11 I used it (11.4) by installing this item and its corresponding cudnn version (8.2.4.15), the problem seems to be solved, the gpu is detected and the previous warnings are not displayed.
Note: Be sure to modify the cudnn environment variables afterwards. If needed, uninstall and install tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case you dont have the right cuda version installed for your tensorflow version:

```
cudart64_110.dll not found
```

this error hints that the cudart dll which is installed with cuda in version 110 --> 11.0 is missing. Therefore i would try cuda version 11. In the following blog post a similar problem is discussed and there cuda version 11.2 is recommended for TF 2.10.

https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-to-activate-gpu-in-tensorflow/16888/3

### What was causing the problem?

AS you are on Windows you need to cant install the newest version of tensorflow but installed a the newest version of CUDA which is not compatible anymore.

> Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native

Comment: I already read this, according to the site's description, the latest version before 2.11 should be installed:
python -m pip install "tensorflow<2.11"
which is version 2.10.1

Comment: Sorry i missed that you were already using the correct TF version. Editted post accordingly with new possible solution.