# RuntimeError: GET was unable to find an engine to execute this computation when I using Trainer.train() from hungingface

Tags: pytorch, get, runtime-error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [46], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train_results = trainer.train()
      2 wandb.finish()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1543, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1538     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1540 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1541     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1542 )
-> 1543 return inner_training_loop(
   1544     args=args,
   1545     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1546     trial=trial,
   1547     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1548 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1791, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1789         tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1790 else:
-> 1791     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1793 if (
   1794     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   1795     and not is_torch_tpu_available()
   1796     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   1797 ):
   1798     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   1799     tr_loss += tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2539, in Trainer.training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2536     return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)
   2538 with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2539     loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2541 if self.args.n_gpu > 1:
   2542     loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2571, in Trainer.compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2569 else:
   2570     labels = None
-> 2571 outputs = model(**inputs)
   2572 # Save past state if it exists
   2573 # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.
   2574 if self.args.past_index >= 0:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/swinv2/modeling_swinv2.py:1274, in Swinv2ForImageClassification.forward(self, pixel_values, head_mask, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1266 r"""
   1267 labels (`torch.LongTensor` of shape `(batch_size,)`, *optional*):
   1268     Labels for computing the image classification/regression loss. Indices should be in `[0, ...,
   1269     config.num_labels - 1]`. If `config.num_labels == 1` a regression loss is computed (Mean-Square loss), If
   1270     `config.num_labels > 1` a classification loss is computed (Cross-Entropy).
   1271 """
   1272 return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
-> 1274 outputs = self.swinv2(
   1275     pixel_values,
   1276     head_mask=head_mask,
   1277     output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1278     output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
   1279     return_dict=return_dict,
   1280 )
   1282 pooled_output = outputs[1]
   1284 logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/swinv2/modeling_swinv2.py:1076, in Swinv2Model.forward(self, pixel_values, bool_masked_pos, head_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1069 # Prepare head mask if needed
   1070 # 1.0 in head_mask indicate we keep the head
   1071 # attention_probs has shape bsz x n_heads x N x N
   1072 # input head_mask has shape [num_heads] or [num_hidden_layers x num_heads]
   1073 # and head_mask is converted to shape [num_hidden_layers x batch x num_heads x seq_length x seq_length]
   1074 head_mask = self.get_head_mask(head_mask, len(self.config.depths))
-> 1076 embedding_output, input_dimensions = self.embeddings(pixel_values, bool_masked_pos=bool_masked_pos)
   1078 encoder_outputs = self.encoder(
   1079     embedding_output,
   1080     input_dimensions,
   (...)
   1084     return_dict=return_dict,
   1085 )
   1087 sequence_output = encoder_outputs[0]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/swinv2/modeling_swinv2.py:295, in Swinv2Embeddings.forward(self, pixel_values, bool_masked_pos)
    292 def forward(
    293     self, pixel_values: Optional[torch.FloatTensor], bool_masked_pos: Optional[torch.BoolTensor] = None
    294 ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor]:
--> 295     embeddings, output_dimensions = self.patch_embeddings(pixel_values)
    296     embeddings = self.norm(embeddings)
    297     batch_size, seq_len, _ = embeddings.size()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/swinv2/modeling_swinv2.py:353, in Swinv2PatchEmbeddings.forward(self, pixel_values)
    351 # pad the input to be divisible by self.patch_size, if needed
    352 pixel_values = self.maybe_pad(pixel_values, height, width)
--> 353 embeddings = self.projection(pixel_values)
    354 _, _, height, width = embeddings.shape
    355 output_dimensions = (height, width)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:463, in Conv2d.forward(self, input)
    462 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 463     return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:459, in Conv2d._conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    455 if self.padding_mode != 'zeros':
    456     return F.conv2d(F.pad(input, self._reversed_padding_repeated_twice, mode=self.padding_mode),
    457                     weight, bias, self.stride,
    458                     _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459 return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    460                 self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: GET was unable to find an engine to execute this computation
```

I'm not sure that what happen basically this error NOT show when I run my pipeline but a few day ago is appear. How to fix them

Swintransformer from hunggingface : 'microsoft/swinv2-tiny-patch4-window8-256'
from transformers import AutoModelForImageClassification, AutoImageProcessor

!pip install transformers==4.26.0
!pip3 install torch torchvision --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
!pip install tensorflow --upgrade

How to fix them to working NOT error.........

Comment: I had this problem, turns out all that was needed was a reboot (I didn't reboot after driver installation).

Answer (score 6):

Compare cuda version returned by `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc --version`. They need to match. Then you are good to go.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. This [popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504578/1804173) suggests otherwise, and I've successfully used CUDA with non-matching versions between the two.

Comment: in one instance, this problem happened because cuda compat 11.8 was installed. After uninstalling that, then nvcc was disabled and it worked

Answer (score 5):

First of all check your CUDA settings.
I had exactly the same error today, with ResNet-18, and the source of the problem was incorrect CUDA version. What is worth to examine:
what is your OS?
look at the output of nvidia-smi
look at the output of nvcc --version and check if CUDA version reported is the one expected
I also suggest to put print(os.environ) at the beginnig of your script and examine:

- cuda related paths in PATH variable used by the script
- value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH used by the script

Comment: I installed gpu driver following google GCP instruction [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-gpu-installation/tree/main/linux), nvidia-smi returns `NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.12    Driver Version: 525.85.12    CUDA Version: 12.0` while nvcc returns `Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I faced this problem while the gpu does not have enough memory. Reducing the bathsize or training with amp may be helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: I had the same issue. GPU memory was getting full. Deleting large unwanted vars might help.

Answer (score 1):

Updating pytorch to the latest version compatible with the CUDA version displayed in my nvidia-smi solves this issue for me:

- type nvidia-smi in terminal
- check the version in "CUDA Version"
- go to https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ to find the command you should type in terminal compatible with your CUDA version - installing with conda is recommended
- launch the conda command given to update pytorch

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with FIND instead of GET and the reason was just that my GPU was already being used. So it can be misleading.

Run `nvidia-smi` to make sure it's not the case and run first on an empty GPU that you know the model will fit in.

Answer (score 1):

Check **CUDA version** and that should be compatible with **torch version** otherwise you will get this error.

Here is the link to find suitable CUDA and torch version for installation.
 https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

In my case, i managed to solve this issue by downgrading pytorch from 2.0.1 to 1.8 and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

got this error after installing `tlp`, which must have messed my nvidia settings; reverting to 'performance mode' profile solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear cache for the GPU
And if you are single GPU:
replace

> device = 'cuda'

with

> device = 'cuda:0'

Answer (score 0):

Check the CUDA version using `nvcc --version`, DO NOT use nvidia-smi for checking the CUDA version as it shows the CUDA version that is supported by the drivers installed.
Then simply uninstall pytorch using `pip uninstall torch`, and then download pytorch following the CUDA version you got earlier.