# Docker CUDA question (differ from system CUDA version)

Tags: docker, cuda

I'm developing code on CUDA 12.2, however I have to run script on CUDA 10.2
Thus, I decided to use docker images with cuda 10.2 (GPU enabled)

After I create container like below

```
docker pull andrewseidl/nvidia-cuda:10.2-devel-ubuntu20.04
docker run --name try1 -it -v "$PWD/try1:/home" --ipc host --gpus all fa1cbb599171 /bin/bash
nvidia-smi
nvcc -V
```

I observed that `nvidia-smi` returns CUDA 12.2, while `nvcc -V` returns 12.1. What could be the issue?

Interestingly, when I attempt to install the code using `pip install .`, I encounter the following error:

```
The detected CUDA version (12.1) mismatches the version that was used to compile
PyTorch (10.2). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.
```

What might be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: `nvidia-smi` reporting 12.2 is expected behavior. It just reports the maximum supported version of the driver. It has nothing to do with the CUDA Toolkit that is installed on top. See [Different CUDA versions shown by nvcc and NVIDIA-smi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422407/10107454). Why the wrong version of the Toolkit seems to be installed might only be answerable with the Dockerfile.

Comment: For creating sane Dockerfiles installing a certain version of the CUDA Toolkit on a certain OS, I can recommend [NVIDIA/hpc-container-maker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/hpc-container-maker/tree/master).

Comment: I think this question shouldn't have been marked as a duplicate, as the linked question only answers part of the problem. It should have been closed for missing debugging information instead.