# ImportError: libcudart.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, large-language-model

I am very new to LLM serving and quantization. Any leads would be much appreciated. I am trying to quantize my model using Autoawq. I have installed the following packages:

```
Package            Version
------------------ ------------
absl-py            2.0.0
accelerate         0.24.1
aiohttp            3.9.0
aiosignal          1.3.1
annotated-types    0.6.0
anyio              3.7.1
async-timeout      4.0.3
attributedict      0.3.0
attrs              23.1.0
autoawq            0.1.7
blessings          1.7
cachetools         5.3.2
certifi            2022.12.7
chardet            5.2.0
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
click              8.1.7
codecov            2.1.13
colorama           0.4.6
coloredlogs        15.0.1
colour-runner      0.1.1
coverage           7.3.2
DataProperty       1.0.1
datasets           2.15.0
deepdiff           6.7.1
dill               0.3.7
distlib            0.3.7
distro             1.8.0
exceptiongroup     1.1.3
filelock           3.9.0
frozenlist         1.4.0
fsspec             2023.4.0
h11                0.14.0
httpcore           1.0.2
httpx              0.25.1
huggingface-hub    0.19.4
humanfriendly      10.0
idna               3.4
inspecta           0.1.3
Jinja2             3.1.2
joblib             1.3.2
jsonlines          4.0.0
lm-eval            0.3.0
MarkupSafe         2.1.3
mbstrdecoder       1.1.3
mpmath             1.3.0
multidict          6.0.4
multiprocess       0.70.15
networkx           3.0
nltk               3.8.1
numexpr            2.8.6
numpy              1.24.1
openai             1.3.3
ordered-set        4.1.0
packaging          23.2
pandas             2.0.3
pathvalidate       3.2.0
Pillow             9.3.0
pip                19.3.1
platformdirs       4.0.0
pluggy             1.3.0
portalocker        2.8.2
protobuf           4.25.1
psutil             5.9.6
pyarrow            14.0.1
pyarrow-hotfix     0.5
pybind11           2.11.1
pycountry          22.3.5
pydantic           2.5.1
pydantic-core      2.14.3
pygments           2.17.1
pyproject-api      1.6.1
pytablewriter      1.2.0
python-dateutil    2.8.2
pytz               2023.3.post1
PyYAML             6.0.1
regex              2023.10.3
requests           2.28.1
rootpath           0.1.1
rouge-score        0.1.2
sacrebleu          1.5.0
safetensors        0.4.0
scikit-learn       1.3.2
scipy              1.10.1
sentencepiece      0.1.99
setuptools         41.6.0
six                1.16.0
sniffio            1.3.0
sqlitedict         2.1.0
sympy              1.12
tabledata          1.3.3
tabulate           0.9.0
tcolorpy           0.1.4
termcolor          2.3.0
texttable          1.7.0
threadpoolctl      3.2.0
tokenizers         0.15.0
toml               0.10.2
tomli              2.0.1
torch              2.1.1+cu118
torchaudio         2.1.1+cu118
torchvision        0.16.1+cu118
tox                4.11.3
tqdm               4.66.1
tqdm-multiprocess  0.0.11
transformers       4.35.2
triton             2.1.0
typepy             1.3.2
typing-extensions  4.4.0
tzdata             2023.3
urllib3            1.26.13
virtualenv         20.24.6
xxhash             3.4.1
yarl               1.9.2
zstandard          0.22.0
```

I am trying run the sample code from https://github.com/casper-hansen/AutoAWQ:

```
from awq import AutoAWQForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_path = 'lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.5'
quant_path = 'vicuna-7b-v1.5-awq'
quant_config = { "zero_point": True, "q_group_size": 128, "w_bit": 4, "version": "GEMM" }

# Load model
model = AutoAWQForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, trust_remote_code=True)

# Quantize
model.quantize(tokenizer, quant_config=quant_config)

# Save quantized model
model.save_quantized(quant_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(quant_path)
```

However I get the following error:

```
/usr/test3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_runtime.py:184: UserWarning: Pydantic is installed but cannot be imported. Please check your installation. `huggingface_hub` will default to not using Pydantic. Error message: '{e}'
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quant.py", line 1, in <module>
    from awq import AutoAWQForCausalLM
  File "/usr/test3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awq/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from awq.models.auto import AutoAWQForCausalLM
  File "/usr/test3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awq/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mpt import MptAWQForCausalLM
  File "/usr/test3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awq/models/mpt.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseAWQForCausalLM
  File "/usr/test3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awq/models/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from awq.quantize.quantizer import AwqQuantizer
  File "/usr/test3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awq/quantize/quantizer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from awq.modules.linear import WQLinear_GEMM, WQLinear_GEMV
  File "/usr/test3/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awq/modules/linear.py", line 4, in <module>
    import awq_inference_engine  # with CUDA kernels
ImportError: libcudart.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is my nvidia config:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A10          Off  | 00000000:17:00.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   40C    P0    59W / 150W |  18106MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A10          Off  | 00000000:31:00.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   28C    P8    21W / 150W |      2MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA A10          Off  | 00000000:B1:00.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   26C    P8    20W / 150W |      2MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA A10          Off  | 00000000:CA:00.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   26C    P8    20W / 150W |      2MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the nvcc --version output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_14_21:12:58_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0
```

Comment: You are only showing your driver version, [the CUDA version in `nvidia-smi` is just the maximum supported by the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422407/10107454). What is the output from `nvcc --version`?

Comment: Considering that the `.12` in `libcudart.so.12` stands for CUDA 12, you will probably need to update both the Nvidia driver and the CUDA Toolkit.

Comment: This is the nvcc version:
```nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_14_21:12:58_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0```

Comment: Is there a way for me to downgrade my torch version to something thats compatible to the current nvidia driver and CUDA toolkit? According to ```https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/``` I am using the correct version of torch right?

Comment: You can compile modern pytorch against cuda 11 yourself if need be. Just don't use someone else's binaries compiled against cuda 12 when you're on a distro that packages cuda 11.

Comment: (that is to say, any given version of the pytorch _source_ is compatible with multiple versions of cuda; it's a question of which cuda headers and library were installed at compile time when the _binaries_ you installed were produced)

Comment: Please edit the nvcc version into the question. Comments are not the right place for critical information.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on using AWQ in Runpod recently. Faced the same issue. So by default using nvidia-smi saw that the cuda version was 12.3 .
Resolved the issue by using these commands to install the libraries.

!pip -q install --upgrade fschat accelerate autoawq vllm

!pip install torch==2.1.0+cu121 torchvision==0.16.0+cu121 torchaudio==2.1.0 torchtext==0.16.0+cpu torchdata==0.7.0 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121

Link to the solution
https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/1718

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar question when I try to import transformers.
My attempt may be helpful to you.
I try to install pydantic and have a result of it.

```
$ pip install pydantic
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic in ./.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: annotated-types>=0.4.0 in ./.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pydantic) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic-core==2.14.6 in ./.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pydantic) (2.14.6)
Collecting typing-extensions>=4.6.1 (from pydantic)
  Downloading typing_extensions-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Downloading typing_extensions-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions
  Attempting uninstall: typing-extensions
    Found existing installation: typing_extensions 4.5.0
    Uninstalling typing_extensions-4.5.0:
      Successfully uninstalled typing_extensions-4.5.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
triton 2.0.0 requires cmake, which is not installed.
triton 2.0.0 requires lit, which is not installed.
tensorflow 2.13.1 requires typing-extensions<4.6.0,>=3.6.6, but you have typing-extensions 4.9.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-cpu 2.13.1 requires typing-extensions<4.6.0,>=3.6.6, but you have typing-extensions 4.9.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed typing-extensions-4.9.0
```

Even though there are some errors, I can still normally import transformers.