# segmentation fault error when i use gemm function of DPC++ blas library on NVIDIA-GPU

Tags: nvidia, intel-oneapi, sycl, dpc++

I installed oneAPI base kit and HPC kit (2024.0) on public cluster to test the performance of gemm.
but I got segmentation fault error. I don't know how to fix this problem.

I used offline installer and installed it locally.
I also followed the instruction in the following webpage to configure nvidia gpu.
https://developer.codeplay.com/products/oneapi/nvidia/2024.0.0/guides/get-started-guide-nvidia.html#dpc-resources

Here is the result.

```
SYCL_PI_TRACE\[basic\]: Plugin found and successfully loaded: libpi_cuda.so \[ PluginVersion: 14.38.1 \]
SYCL_PI_TRACE\[basic\]: Plugin found and successfully loaded: libpi_unified_runtime.so \[ PluginVersion: 14.37.1 \]
SYCL_PI_TRACE\[all\]: Requested device_type: info::device_type::automatic
SYCL_PI_TRACE\[all\]: Requested device_type: info::device_type::automatic
SYCL_PI_TRACE\[all\]: Selected device: -\> final score = 1500
SYCL_PI_TRACE\[all\]:   platform: NVIDIA CUDA BACKEND
SYCL_PI_TRACE\[all\]:   device: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB
The results are correct!
```

I compiled the test program provided in the following github link using the following options.
https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneMKL/blob/89cfda5c360b34a21f280ae11ecc00abd8e350f4/examples/blas/run_time_dispatching/level3/gemm_usm.cpp

> icpx -fsycl -fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda -Xsycl-target-backend=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_70 gemm_usm.cpp -o dpcpp_dgemm_v100 -Wl,-rpath=/home01/r907a03/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.0/lib /home01/r907a03/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.0/lib/libmkl_sycl_blas.so /home01/r907a03/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.0/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.so /home01/r907a03/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.0/lib/libmkl_tbb_thread.so /home01/r907a03/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.0/lib/libmkl_core.so /home01/r907a03/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.11/lib/libtbb.so.12

I also used the following option to detect gpu device automatically.

> export ONEAPI_DEVICE_SELECTOR="ext_oneapi_cuda:*"

here is the result.

```
########################################################################
# General Matrix-Matrix Multiplication using Unified Shared Memory Example:
#
# C = alpha * A * B + beta * C
#
# where A, B and C are general dense matrices and alpha, beta are
# floating point type precision scalars.
#
# Using apis:
#   gemm
#
# Using single precision (float) data type
#
# Device will be selected during runtime.
# The environment variable SYCL_DEVICE_FILTER can be used to specify
# SYCL device
#
########################################################################

Running BLAS GEMM USM example on GPU device.
Device name is: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB
Running with single precision real data type:
Segmentation fault
```

I don't know how can I troubleshoot this problem.

I also tried to set "export LIBOMPTARGET_PLUGIN=OPENCL"
It doesn't work either.
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/MKL-examples-segmentation-fault/td-p/1213659

I also tried other gemm example, and it does not work either.
https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/tree/master/Libraries/oneMKL/matrix_mul_mkl
To force the program to select gpu device, I used
`queue Q( gpu_selector_v );`

---

Here are the system information

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

GCC version 12.2.0

CUDA version 12.1

```
$ nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:18:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   27C    P0    25W / 250W |      4MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0    27W / 250W |      4MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
$ sycl-ls
[opencl:acc:0] Intel(R) FPGA Emulation Platform for OpenCL(TM), Intel(R) FPGA Emulation Device OpenCL 1.2  [2023.16.10.0.17_160000]
[opencl:cpu:1] Intel(R) OpenCL, Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R CPU @ 2.90GHz OpenCL 3.0 (Build 0) [2023.16.10.0.17_160000]
[opencl:cpu:2] Intel(R) OpenCL, Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R CPU @ 2.90GHz OpenCL 3.0 (Build 0) [2021.12.9.0.24_005321]
[ext_oneapi_cuda:gpu:0] NVIDIA CUDA BACKEND, Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB 7.0 [CUDA 11.6]
[ext_oneapi_cuda:gpu:1] NVIDIA CUDA BACKEND, Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB 7.0 [CUDA 11.6]
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the segfaults, but your CUDA driver only supports up to CUDA 11.6. Updating it to support CUDA 12.1 might help.

Comment: I used cuda 12.1 but nvidia-smi said 11.6. I don't know why.. @paleonix

Comment: Because that is the maximum CUDA version supported by your Nvidia driver. See [Different CUDA versions shown by nvcc and NVIDIA-smi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422407/10107454).

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering where does the `libmkl_sycl_blas.so` come from? It might be an old version since the SYCL library you're linking against changed to [portBLAS](https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/portBLAS) so you should rather use the lib with this name `libonemkl_blas_portblas.so` if you want to use portBLAS backend with oneMKL.

Also it never occured to me to use `--offload-arch=sm_70` but rather `--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_70`.

Comment: I got libmkl_sycl_blas.so from the makefile of one of the example provided by intel. I found several example files which essentially do the same thing, but they did not specified the version of sycl. If you are familiar with the SYCL library or DPC++, please let me know where should I start to learn this.

Comment: Thanks to your explanation, I installed portblas from https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/portBLAS. I still have similar problem.

./bench_gemm --device=nvidia:gpu

`Native API failed. Native API returns: -42 (PI_ERROR_INVALID_BINARY) -42 (PI_ERROR_INVALID_BINARY)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sycl::_V1::runtime_error'
  what():  Enqueue process failed. -59 (PI_ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION)`

Comment: should I install cublas before I use portblas?

Comment: portBLAS is an independent BLAS implementation, and does not depend on cuBLAS. cuBLAS is a supported BLAS backend in oneMKL if you choose to enable it (see the oneMKL docs). 
You also shouldn't need to download and build portBLAS separately. oneMKL can download and install this automatically if it isn't found.
I think the point that Ouadie is trying to make is that you may be working with an old version of oneMKL (and consequently, an old version of portBLAS). SYCL-BLAS was renamed to portBLAS in a commit in September, so a recent version should link against `libonemkl_blas_portblas.so`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because cuBLAS is not in the system, and it is defaulting to the MKL CPU and GPU versions for Intel Platforms. The dynamic dispatch is not supported for NVIDIA platforms on that particular release AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with `@Ruyk`'s answer, if you want to run the oneMKL GEMM sample on the NVIDIA GPUs, it's best if you use the open-source oneMKL interfaces repository to build the above example with `-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON` following the documentation mentioned here:
https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneMKL/blob/develop/docs/building_the_project.rst#building-for-cuda-with-clang

Answer (score 0):

As for the use of `portBLAS`, running `bench_gemm` on NVIDIA_GPU would run the open-source SYCL implementation of GEMM algorithm available here: https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/portBLAS/blob/master/src/operations/blas3/gemm_local.hpp. This benchmark won't require `cublas`, however you can also run `cublas::gemm` benchmark through `portBLAS` if you have `cublas` installed by setting the cmake flag `-DBUILD_CUBLAS_BENCHMARKS=ON`.
If you are interested in pursuing this further, than you can try and use the following commands and see if it resolves your issue or not.

```
source /path/to/setvars.sh
export CC=/path/to/clang
export CXX=/path/to/clang++
export PORTBLAS_DIR=/path/to/portBLAS

cd $PORTBLAS_DIR
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -GNinja $PORTBLAS_DIR -DSYCL_COMPILER=dpcpp \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
-DTUNING_TARGET="NVIDIA_GPU" \
-DDPCPP_SYCL_TARGET="nvptx64-nvidia-cuda" \
-DDPCPP_SYCL_ARCH="sm_70" \
-DENABLE_EXPRESSION_TESTS=OFF \
-DBLAS_BUILD_SAMPLES=OFF \
-DBLAS_ENABLE_COMPLEX=OFF \
-DBLAS_ENABLE_BENCHMARK=ON \
-DBUILD_CUBLAS_BENCHMARKS=ON \
-DBLAS_VERIFY_BENCHMARK=ON \
-DBLAS_ENABLE_CONST_INPUT=OFF \
-DBLAS_ENABLE_TESTING=OFF 

ninja bench_gemm
./benchmark/portblas/bench_gemm --device=nvidia:gpu
ninja bench_cublas_gemm
./benchmark/cublas/bench_cublas_gemm
```