# NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.15 with CUDA Version: 12.4

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, cudnn

I recently purchased and setup a new desktop computer and have been having trouble getting the GPU drivers to work completely.

The system has:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
GEFORCE RTX 4070
NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.15
CUDA Version: 12.4

When I visit the Nvidia driver page: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/reference/support-matrix.html
CUDA version 12.3 is the latest one listed for Linux.

I'm working on training various NNs, and would like to utilize the GPU that is installed.

I'm wondering if I need to compile drivers from source, or if there is an easier way.  Here is an error I get when launching tensorboard (for example):

'''

```
024-03-27 13:07:12.629153: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-03-27 13:07:12.651926: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-03-27 13:07:14.093163: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-03-27 13:07:14.921117: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-03-27 13:07:14.942902: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

NOTE: Using experimental fast data loading logic. To disable, pass
    "--load_fast=false" and report issues on GitHub. More details:
    https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/4784

Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.16.2 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

'''

Comment: I just found a driver for Ubuntu 22.04 and CUDA 12.4, provided by NVIDIA. I'm working to get it installed and setup now. If I run into issues, I'll add more information here. If it is successful, I'll describe what I did and close this issue as solved.

Comment: The driver is backward compatible with older CUDA Toolkits. Just keep it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Different CUDA versions shown by nvcc and NVIDIA-smi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422407/10107454).

Comment: I.e. you need to install the right version of the Toolkit. The driver supporting a newer Toolkit is not a problem.