PyTorch 1.7.1 unable to detect CUDA version 11.0
PyTorch unable to locate the CUDA version in my GPU enabled machine. However the CUDA 11.0 is installed in my machine. The graphic card is  GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER provided by NVIDIA. The GPU and CUDA configuration can be found in the following picture

I also tried the command !python -m torch.utils.collect_env on the Jupyter notebook to verify the environment setup which returned,
Collecting environment information...
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1607370120218/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:100.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
PyTorch version: 1.7.1
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.0
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: version 3.16.3

Python version: 3.6 (64-bit runtime)
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 10.1.243
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER
Nvidia driver version: 450.119.03
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.19.2
[pip3] torch==1.7.1
[pip3] torchaudio==0.7.0a0+a853dff
[pip3] torchvision==0.8.2
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl  
[conda] cudatoolkit               11.0.221             h6bb024c_0  
[conda] mkl                       2020.2                      256  
[conda] mkl-service               2.3.0            py36he8ac12f_0  
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py36h54f3939_0  
[conda] mkl_random                1.1.1            py36h0573a6f_0  
[conda] numpy                     1.19.2           py36h54aff64_0  
[conda] numpy-base                1.19.2           py36hfa32c7d_0  
[conda] pytorch                   1.7.1           py3.6_cuda11.0.221_cudnn8.0.5_0    pytorch
[conda] torchaudio                0.7.2                      py36    pytorch
[conda] torchvision               0.8.2                py36_cu110    pytorch

torch.cuda.is_available() returned False and
print(torch.backends.cudnn.enabled) returned True
The command I used to install the PyTorch is conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

“ CUDA runtime version: 10.1.243” — that’s not CUDA 11.0

What about nvidia-smi command? It showed CUDA 11.0

That only shows the driver maximum compatibility level. It says nothing about what CUDA toolkit version(s), if any, you might have installed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-sm

@talonmies, if I am not mistaken the "CUDA runtime version" is the one installed on the machine but isn't needed by PyTorch since it comes with its own (here compiled with version 11.0.221)

@Ivan, you are mistaken. And whether Pytorch is actually using the libraries it was built and packaged with, or is picking up others because of library search order or general installation breakage is at the heart of this question

@talonmies I don't agree, why is there an installation breakage? OP specified the command used to install pytorch cudatoolkit version 11.0, and this is the version that is shown in the library list (pytorch cuda11.0.221...). As for whether PyTorch is using the library on the machine, refer to this.

@Encipher, could you try installing pytorch with a different (lower) CUDA toolkit version? For example 10.1 is still compatible with your gpu compute capability: conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch.

@ivan — what don’t you agree with? If you inspect the script which the OP ran, you will see that it pulls its output for the CUDA tool kit version from nvcc run from a subshell. That’s means there is a CUDA 10.1 installation in a very easy to find place. It follows that the python interpreter will find that installation’s runtime libraries, probably before the runtime hidden in a Conda environment path.  And produce a version conflict and failure.

@talonmies, I see what you are saying. Sorry I was not clear, what I meant is, I have read many sources stating that PyTorch will not interfere with the currently installed version because it is shipped with its own CUDA toolkit (potentially of a different version). That is why I am saying the version shown in the logs (CUDA runtime version: 10.1.243) has no implication on whether PyTorch runs on the GPU or not.

Cross post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-cannot-found-cuda-version-11-0-for-nvidia-geforce-rtx-2070-super/200261

@Ivan, yes I did. But CUDA is still unavailable. Can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78299543/unable-to-find-cuda-environment
