Have to export CUDNN_PATH every time I want to use GPU with Tensorflow (WSL)
I have the issue that, when installing the newest version of Tensorflow (2.16.1) that it is not using the GPU.
Only after running the following commands it recognizes the GPU (as suggested in this post Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices):
export CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDNN_PATH}/lib

However, I need to re run these every time I restart my terminal. Is there way to solve this, such that I do not have to re run this all the time? Or should I just add these two lines at the bottom of my .bashrc file?
From nvcc -V I get:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jan__6_16:45:21_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.140
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.32267302_0

And from nvidia-smi I get:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.76.01              Driver Version: 552.44         CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070        On  |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 49%   50C    P8             25W /  240W |    1303MiB /   8192MiB |      3%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        44      G   /Xwayland                                   N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I am also a bit confused that the CUDA Versions of these do not match. nvidia-smi returns 'CUDA Version: 12.4', whereas nvcc -V returns 'V12.0.140'.

"However, I need to re run these every time I restart my terminal"
That is normal for linux-like environments.
It is a common question and you can find many articles showing how to make your env var declarations persist (such as here).  "I am also a bit confused that the CUDA Versions of these do not match. nvidia-smi returns CUDA Version: 12.4, whereas nvcc -V returns V12.0.140" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi

I actually just found a solution to this because. At first I tried adding to the ~/.bash_profile as permanent environment variables, but it kept throwing an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nvidia'

I think its due to the different paths being used due to anaconda.
I ended up doing the following.
Create the following and navigate there:
mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
cd $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda
touch ./activate.d/env_vars.sh

Open it:
cd activate.d
sudo nano env_vars.sh

And paste there:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LS_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/

Now I can see my GPU every time I test this command:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

