CUDA program to add two integers does not work
This is the example program "simple_kernel_params.cu" from the book CUDA By Example by Jason Sanders and Edward Kandrot.
#include <cstdio>

static void HandleError(cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), file, line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

#define HANDLE_ERROR(err) (HandleError(err, __FILE__, __LINE__))

__global__ void add(int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c = a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int *dev_c;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_c, sizeof(int)));
    add<<<1, 1>>>(2, 7, dev_c);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(&c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("2 + 7 = %d\n", c); // prints "2 + 7 = 0"
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaFree(dev_c));
    return 0;
}

The output should be 2 + 7 = 9 but instead it is 2 + 7 = 0.
I know that one issue may be that the NVIDIA drivers have not been initialized, so here is the (abridged) output from sudo nvidia-smi -a. (I couldn't paste the entire output because StackOverflow complains that "your post is mostly code; please add some more details")
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Driver Version                            : 535.104.12
CUDA Version                              : 12.2

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:00:1E.0
    Product Name                          : Tesla T4
    Product Brand                         : NVIDIA
    Product Architecture                  : Turing
    Display Mode                          : Disabled
    Display Active                        : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                      : Enabled
    Addressing Mode                       : None
    MIG Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Accounting Mode                       : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size           : 4000
    Driver Model
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Serial Number                         : 1563820001764
    GPU UUID                              : GPU-c4636f1c-e8b5-a646-1c6d-14eb842ae426
    Minor Number                          : 0
    VBIOS Version                         : 90.04.96.00.02
    MultiGPU Board                        : No
    Board ID                              : 0x1e
    Board Part Number                     : 900-2G183-0000-001
    GPU Part Number                       : 1EB8-895-A1
    FRU Part Number                       : N/A
    Module ID                             : 1
    Inforom Version
        Image Version                     : G183.0200.00.02
        OEM Object                        : 1.1
        ECC Object                        : 5.0
        Power Management Object           : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    GSP Firmware Version                  : 535.104.12
    GPU Virtualization Mode
        Virtualization Mode               : Pass-Through
        Host VGPU Mode                    : N/A
    GPU Reset Status
        Reset Required                    : No
        Drain and Reset Recommended       : N/A
    IBMNPU
        Relaxed Ordering Mode             : N/A

Why doesn't my program work?

You can use CUDA GDB to see what is going on. You can also use printf to see the values. Nshight and NVPP might also help for synchronization issue. What if you use the default stream instead of a specific stream?

@JérômeRichard You mean add a printf inside add? I tried that but it didn't print anything...
Also how do I use the default stream?

Output from cuda-gdb:
(cuda-gdb) run
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff5346000 (LWP 49569)]
[Detaching after fork from child process 49570]
[New Thread 0x7fffe9fff000 (LWP 49580)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe97fe000 (LWP 49581)]
warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaLaunchKernel returned (0xde)
2 + 7 = 0
[Thread 0x7ffff5346000 (LWP 49569) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe97fe000 (LWP 49581) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe9fff000 (LWP 49580) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 49562) exited normally]

0xde = 222 = "provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain"  Your CUDA install on your machine is not correct.  The nvcc version you are using is inconsistent with your GPU driver version.  A simple fix could be to update the GPU driver to the latest available for your GPU.  And your error checking is insufficient.  Try doing HANDLE_ERROR(cudaGetLastError()); right after the kernel call.

@RobertCrovella Thank you. I updated the driver and this fixed the problem. I did not realize that the CUDA version displayed by nvidia-smi is not necessarily the installed version from nvcc --version.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi

Your program does works correctly if I copy paste your code in Godbolt:
https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/xMeK74rc6
The problem is not with the code, but with your CUDA installation.
Clean the computer and reinstall CUDA and the latest NVidia video drivers from scratch.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
